# How to make one argument imply another without needing an explicit value? (--foo, not --foo true)

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, clap

I want one argument to imply another, though they don't take explicit values. `--simple-anime` or `--complex-anime` should imply `--anime`. The API that should work is `default_value_ifs`, saying that if either of the former is present, `--anime` will also be true. The problem is that that option turns on `takes_value`, and if I turn that off, the implication doesn't happen.

Simple example: `--dog` implies `--mammal`. Neither one should require a value--it is true if the argument is present.

```
use clap::Parser;

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse_from(["prog-name", "--dog"]);
    assert_eq!(args.dog, true);
    assert_eq!(args.mammal, true);
    dbg!(&args);
    
    let args = Args::try_parse_from(["prog-name", "--mammal"]);
    dbg!(&args);
    assert!(matches!(args, Ok(_)));
}


#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap()]
struct Args {
    //#[clap(long, default_value_if("dog", None, Some("true")), takes_value(false))]
    #[clap(long, default_value_if("dog", None, Some("true")))]
    mammal: bool,

    #[clap(long)]
    dog: bool,
}
```

Try it in rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4855a88381f65cef8d07f7eab4d41e78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `takes_value(false)` use `min_values(0)` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fac88b5a41b5d27deb983b5d000b0b04)):

```
#[clap(long, default_value_if("dog", None, Some("true")), min_values(0))]
    mammal: bool,
```

It looks like the default value implementation uses the same code as the *values*, so if you disable one you disable the other.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726367/1003451) @rodrigo posted no longer works with the current version of clap (4.4.0).  I fixed it: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a0e9b32876f06679f6cc1114d80ce504))

```rust
    #[clap(long, default_value_if("dog", "true", Some("true")))]
    mammal: bool,
```